# PySpark: how to do efficient grouping all values by key column

Tags: apache-spark, mapreduce, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I got the following Spark dataframe, which is partitioned by Variable.

```
+--------+--------------------+-------+---+
|Variable|                Time|  Value| id|
+--------+--------------------+-------+---+
|    7508|2015-08-20 12:01:...| 40.175| 16|
|   14491|2015-08-20 12:01:...|-51.787| 16|
|    8309|2015-08-20 12:01:...| 61.093| 16|
|   17051|2015-08-20 12:01:...| 30.362| 16|
|   18259|2015-08-20 12:01:...| 59.118| 16|
|     603|2015-08-20 12:01:...|249.847| 16|
|   10745|2015-08-20 12:01:...| 59.214| 16|
|   17107|2015-08-20 12:01:...| 36.235| 16|
|   18516|2015-08-20 12:01:...|   65.0| 16|
|   12750|2015-08-20 12:01:...| 99.392| 16|
+--------+--------------------+-------+---+
```

The ID column indicates a "small" set of incidents for which the variables values are the observations at a specific time. Now I want to group that data by the incident ID so that I can do some statistics on just those observations for let's say incident ID=16. **Explanation:** my goal is to get all observations for all variables for an incident as input into a user defined method.

My current code is as follow. **Question**: Is there a more efficient way to do that?

```
def combine(iter):
    rows = list(iter)
    if not rows:
        return

    df_pd = pd.DataFrame(rows)
    ... # do some Pandas analytics (on the Spark data node)
    return df_pd

ref = ref.repartition("id").mapPartitions(combine).collect()
```

Comment: can't you just use `groupBy` ?

Comment: I know that there are huge differences in performance. And how would you use map/mapPartitions right after groupBy? Any code example?

Comment: Please make your question more specific, instead of `"do some analytics"`, along with reproducible data, code and expected output.

Comment: Done. But that's not the point here. The point is grouping by incident-id and getting all rows (value observations) for that incident as input-argument into a user-defined function.